# What exactly constitutes a 'term'?

Tags: terminology

From what I understand when I looked up the definition on wikipedia, a term is a monomial with a coefficient. However, I was taught in high school that a term could also be an expression depending on the context -- for instance in

$$
\frac{(x - 2)(2x + 4)}{(2x - 4)}
$$

the expressions **x - 2**, **2x + 4** and **2x - 4** are all terms.

Is this correct terminology? If not, what is the correct terminology to refer to something like this?

My native language is not English so I am interested in knowing the correct terminology so I can easily communicate to others when I am talking about mathematics.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have not run across a strict definition of "term", which may be because it is similar to "element" in that it cannot be defined without a circular definition, but here goes anyways.

> A term of a mathematical object (such as a polynomial, sequence, equation, etc) is one simple "piece" distinguishable from the rest of the "pieces" in some way (i.e., in location or description).

For a polynomial, $f(x) = (x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)\dots(x-\alpha_k)$ you could describe each of the $(x-\alpha_i)$ as separate "terms", where in this case *all of the terms are being multiplied*.  It should be mentioned that this usage of the word is less common, and it is more common to refer to these as "factors".  See [Term or factor?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458494/term-or-factor) This does not stop some people from using the word this way however and you may very well find this usage in various pieces of literature.

More commonly, with $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \dots + a_n x^n$, you could talk about the "$x^2$" term, where $f(x)$ is considered a *summation of terms*.  Similarly, you could have $a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \dots + b_0 + b_1 x + b_2 x^2 + \dots + c_0 + c_1 x + \dots$ and talk about all of the "$x^2$ *terms*".

In both of these cases, you can treat the terms as being elements of a sequence with some operation occurring between them.  Likewise, you can talk about the *"terms" of a sequence*.  Such as the $n$th term in the sequence of Triangle numbers is given by $T(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

What connects all of these examples is that there are many "things" visible in what we are considering and each one of those "things" is colloquially what we call a term.

(other examples:  "group all of the even terms together", "find the coefficient of the $x^2y^3z$ term in $(x+y+z+1)^{10}$")

Additional reading: [mathword: Term](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=term&a=*C.term-_*MathWorld-)

Comment: In mathematical logic 'term" is a technical term; a "term" is a well-formed expression made up of constants, variables, and operation symbols (but not relation symbols). In that sense, $x+yz$ is a term, but the formula $x=yz$ is not a term.